# How to omit waiting for the thread forever after updating table with to_sql? -> how to get out from waiting for a thread

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I'm trying to create a table in the MySQL database and populate it with:

```
  df.to_sql(table_name, con=engine, index=index, 
            if_exists='replace', chunksize=2000)
```

and I succeed to some extent, because I'm creating a table and uploading all the records. Meanwhile the script is still working until I stop it manually, and when I do it always appears to be in threading.py/shutdown/join/_wait_for_tstate_lock. In the libraries it looks like this:

```
def _shutdown():
    # Obscure:  other threads may be waiting to join _main_thread.  That's
    # dubious, but some code does it.  We can't wait for C code to release
    # the main thread's tstate_lock - that won't happen until the interpreter
    # is nearly dead.  So we release it here.  Note that just calling _stop()
    # isn't enough:  other threads may already be waiting on _tstate_lock.
    tlock = _main_thread._tstate_lock
    # The main thread isn't finished yet, so its thread state lock can't have
    # been released.
    assert tlock is not None
    assert tlock.locked()
    tlock.release()
    _main_thread._stop()
    t = _pickSomeNonDaemonThread()
    while t:
        t.join()
        t = _pickSomeNonDaemonThread()


def _wait_for_tstate_lock(self, block=True, timeout=-1):
    # Issue #18808: wait for the thread state to be gone.
    # At the end of the thread's life, after all knowledge of the thread
    # is removed from C data structures, C code releases our _tstate_lock.
    # This method passes its arguments to _tstate_lock.acquire().
    # If the lock is acquired, the C code is done, and self._stop() is
    # called.  That sets ._is_stopped to True, and ._tstate_lock to None.
    lock = self._tstate_lock
    if lock is None:  # already determined that the C code is done
        assert self._is_stopped
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
        lock.release()
        self._stop()
```

I experimented with all the possible parameters in to_sql (chunksize, method etc.) - it changed nothing.

This is the connection code:

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@{host}:{port}/{db}"
                               .format(host=_mysql_host, db=reports_db, user=_mysql_username, pw=_mysql_password,
                                       port=tunnel.local_bind_port))
```